# Which graphics cards are supported by the new AMDGPU driver in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

The new open source AMDGPU driver pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04 should support all the "*Volcanic Islands*" cards out-of-the-box. This means that AMD Radeon R9 285, R9 380/380X and R9 Fury/FuryX graphics cards will be supported out-of-the-box if Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is installed.

However I read that the open source AMDGPU driver has an experimental support for the "*Sea Islands*" graphics cards (HD7790, R7 260, R9 290, R7 360, R9 390).
Is this support enabled by default on Ubuntu 16.04, or will these graphics cards use the Radeon driver?

Thanks

Comment: "Is this optional support enabled by default on Ubuntu 16.04?" Then  what would make that **optional support**?

Comment: @Rinzwind I wrote "optional" since it can be enabled when compiling kernel, if I well understood.

Comment: The new driver doesn't even work on 16.04 yet, so I wouldn't worry about support for Sea Island chipsets just yet...

Answer (score 11):

I believe your answer can be found from the command line.

```
$ man -k amd
amdgpu (4)           - AMD RADEON GPU video driver
pamdeinterlace (1)   - remove ever other row from a PAM/PNM image
pamdice (1)          - slice a Netpbm image into many horizontally and/or vertically
radeon (4)           - ATI/AMD RADEON video driver
```

[`man radeon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/radeon.4) gives a list of supported hardware, as well as a link to their [wiki](https://www.x.org/wiki/radeon/):

```
SUPPORTED HARDWARE
       The radeon driver supports PCI, AGP, and PCIe video cards based on the following ATI/AMD chips
       (note: list is non-exhaustive):

       R100        Radeon 7200
       RV100       Radeon 7000(VE), M6, RN50/ES1000
       RS100       Radeon IGP320(M)
       RV200       Radeon 7500, M7, FireGL 7800
       RS200       Radeon IGP330(M)/IGP340(M)
       RS250       Radeon Mobility 7000 IGP
       R200        Radeon 8500, 9100, FireGL 8800/8700
       RV250       Radeon 9000PRO/9000, M9
       RV280       Radeon 9200PRO/9200/9200SE/9250, M9+
       RS300       Radeon 9100 IGP
       RS350       Radeon 9200 IGP
       RS400/RS480 Radeon XPRESS 200(M)/1100 IGP
       R300        Radeon 9700PRO/9700/9500PRO/9500/9600TX, FireGL X1/Z1
       R350        Radeon 9800PRO/9800SE/9800, FireGL X2
       R360        Radeon 9800XT
       RV350       Radeon 9600PRO/9600SE/9600/9550, M10/M11, FireGL T2
       RV360       Radeon 9600XT
       RV370       Radeon X300, M22
       RV380       Radeon X600, M24
       RV410       Radeon X700, M26 PCIe
       R420        Radeon X800 AGP
       R423/R430   Radeon X800, M28 PCIe
       R480/R481   Radeon X850 PCIe/AGP
       RV505/RV515/RV516/RV550
                   Radeon X1300/X1400/X1500/X1550/X2300
       R520        Radeon X1800
       RV530/RV560 Radeon X1600/X1650/X1700
       RV570/R580  Radeon X1900/X1950
       RS600/RS690/RS740
                   Radeon X1200/X1250/X2100
       R600        Radeon HD 2900
       RV610/RV630 Radeon HD 2400/2600/2700/4200/4225/4250
       RV620/RV635 Radeon HD 3410/3430/3450/3470/3650/3670
       RV670       Radeon HD 3690/3850/3870
       RS780/RS880 Radeon HD 3100/3200/3300/4100/4200/4250/4290
       RV710/RV730 Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550/4650/4670/5145/5165/530v/545v/560v/565v
       RV740/RV770/RV790
                   Radeon HD 4770/4730/4830/4850/4860/4870/4890
       CEDAR       Radeon HD 5430/5450/6330/6350/6370
       REDWOOD     Radeon HD 5550/5570/5650/5670/5730/5750/5770/6530/6550/6570
       JUNIPER     Radeon HD 5750/5770/5830/5850/5870/6750/6770/6830/6850/6870
       CYPRESS     Radeon HD 5830/5850/5870
       HEMLOCK     Radeon HD 5970
       PALM        Radeon HD 6310/6250
       SUMO/SUMO2  Radeon HD 6370/6380/6410/6480/6520/6530/6550/6620
       BARTS       Radeon HD 6790/6850/6870/6950/6970/6990
       TURKS       Radeon HD 6570/6630/6650/6670/6730/6750/6770
       CAICOS      Radeon HD 6430/6450/6470/6490
       CAYMAN      Radeon HD 6950/6970/6990
       ARUBA       Radeon HD 7000 series
       TAHITI      Radeon HD 7900 series
       PITCAIRN    Radeon HD 7800 series
       VERDE       Radeon HD 7700 series
       OLAND       Radeon HD 8000 series
       HAINAN      Radeon HD 8000 series
       BONAIRE     Radeon HD 7790 series
       KAVERI      KAVERI APUs
       KABINI      KABINI APUs
       HAWAII      Radeon R9 series
       MULLINS     MULLINS APUs
```

Reference: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-check-graphics-card-on-linux.html

This is a good tutorial to view information about your GPU.  I especially like `lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"` and `sudo lspci -v -s ##:##.#` (using the numbers you found from the previous command).

Comment: He is asking about the GPUs supported by the AMDGPU driver nor the radeon driver

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of misleading considering that most cards that I know of that are supported by the amdgpu driver are also supported by radeon but like the one I'm currently running runs way better on amdgpu but radeon is the default set after installation.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, the beta drivers have only been tested on ubuntu 14.04 and kernel version 4.2. If you have a Sea Island card, you will need to compile your own kernel with ck enabled. If you're comfortable with the terminal, this is actually pretty easy. You can check the gentoo forums as this is the norm for them. As of right now, unless you are a developer, it is best to avoid the nvidia and amd vulkan drivers. In my experience, they are still experimental and still have many issues on the bleeding edge. My system went down just last week because of a kernel upgrade and the only reason I do use it is because I need to test the framework I'm using on different platforms. For now, stick to the mesa drivers. From what I heard, it is still comparable to the pro driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is surely useful! However in the question I refer to the open source driver **amdgpu** pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I don't refer to the AMD GPU-Pro beta driver provided by AMD on its website.

Comment: question updated :)

Comment: This actually refers to both.   

Basically there are two stacks that use the AMDGPU kernel driver:  AMDGPU/GPU-Pro and AMDGPU/Mesa-Galium 

The AMD GPU-Pro driver uses the same kernel side driver, but uses it's own shader compiler and front end OpenGL libraries.  (It does socket through Mesa nicely for coexistence on platforms with multiple cards unlike the nightmare that was fglrx.)  It also adds Vulkan and OpenCL support. 

GPU-Pro in addition to being closed source does not support the SI chips (i.e. GCN 1.0) it only supports the VI and later chips (i.e. GCN 1.1+)