# ATI Driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics

I am using Gigabyte Motherboard **GA-78LMT-S2**, which have **ATI Radeon 3000** Graphics chip. May I install and use its proprietor Driver on Ubuntu **16.04** without any issue?

Please answer someone.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No. There are no proprietary drivers for your adapter. You can use the default `radeon`.

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility list is here: [Which graphics cards are supported by the new AMDGPU driver in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756258/which-graphics-cards-are-supported-by-the-new-amdgpu-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)

I suspect that it won't work, but you can verify that by downloading the ISO, burning it to disc and then trying the Live CD. If you can operate the Live CD successfully without any hiccups, your video card is supported. Good luck. :)