# Unbuntu, Hashcat and my GPU The answers already posted here don't work, I tried

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, tools, amdgpu-pro

I Ubuntu to use my GPU when I run [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/), and it is not running anywhere near correct when it does run. (I have to enter some of the info backwards.) Here is some of the relevant information.

Computer: HP Desktop Series 8200
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Processor: 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5
RAM: Corsair Vengance Pro Series 24 GB DDR3
Hard drive: Seagate 500 GB SSD
GPU: 4 GB AMD RX 560 LP

See [Hashcat Forums](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-8702-post-46236.html#pid46236). For some reason the bot wont let me post all the relevant info, the inputs and outputs. What follows will make sense if you follow one of the links.

If you notice `sudo DRI_PRIME=1 hashcat -m 2500 -a 3 -o rockyou.txt q.hccapx -w 3` is the only one that sort of works. What I didn't put in is when it's *-a 0* it says the list is too short and starts printing all the words it is excluding.

When I select my GPU to run Hashcat it doesn't see the GPU. I have tried everything possible on here and the internet. I have tried Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, Kali Linux 2019.3 (Rocm ruined two of Kali. It wouldn't boot after install)  and Windows 10 Pro.

In Windows, it won't load the opencl. I just want you to understand I have been battling this for over a week before asking. I almost have it beat; Ubuntu 18.04 is the first time I didn't get any benchmark errors and it has run semi correctly.

I have re-installed it at least twenty times across all the OS cited above.

ROCm says you have held two packages back, and no matter what I do I can't get it installed, or it just kills Kali; it wont reboot after restart into anything other than Live. I had to reinstall Kali at least twice.

Ubuntu already has the drivers in it, I didn't know that, and somehow killed an Ubuntu too, the one and only time I could get them to install.

I spoke to MSI and AMD; they were useless, both said that you can only install it on a Windows system, and they don't even have drivers for Ubuntu or Debian. I said well I guess the drivers that are on the AMD site don't exist then. MSI only has the Windows driver.

Please anyone can you help me fix this problem ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which graphics cards are supported by the new AMDGPU driver in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756258/which-graphics-cards-are-supported-by-the-new-amdgpu-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Gee, if it will not work with four different OS, it's the app or the hardware. Suggest you borrow different hardware, and if fails there, it's certainly either Hashcat or your interpretation of the instructions.

Comment: Thank you, but no. I put the GPU into several computers I have three, it just currently resides in the HP I'm tired of changing it that's not the answer. As for directions I got to the point where I just copy and paste the commands until something doesn't work then I figure it out and move on. I figured out if you go into the driver file and type Kali Linux at the end of the permissions it will load on Kali. That's not what ruined it, that was something to do with ROCm. There was a conflict and I lost Kali twice. That has something to do with drivers too but that is partially a Kali problem.

Comment: I just realized K7 you didn't follow the link I put the directions I followed installing Hashcat in there.